Cloud Run is allocating too many instances
For my Cloud Run service, Both RAM and CPU are low. I don't know why GCP has allocated 6 instances. Its increasing my bill.
CPU is nowhere near the 60% required for scaling.
RAM and CPU:

Instance count:

Interestingly, I have been reducing the CPU and memory limit and the instance count remains unchanged. This has reduced my bill.
I changed from 8GB RAM, 4 core -> 4GB RAM, 2 core -> 1GB RAM, 1 core.
I do not want to goto 512 RAM, <1 CPU.
Is this some dark-pattern by GCP, to increase my bill while I can't do anything about it?
Other config:
General
CPU allocation:
CPU is only allocated during request processing
Startup CPU boost:
Enabled
Concurrency:
80
Request timeout: 300 seconds
Execution environment: Second generation
Auto-scaling
Min instances
2
Max. instances
25
CPU limit
1
Memory limit
1GiB

Its a nextJS server, mainly serving json API calls.

GCP support let me know that at current time, they also look at current effective concurrency capacity instead of maximum capacity value for the container.
Meaning, when you handle slow CPU intensive requests, they lower the effective concurrency capacity of the container. Then that is compared to active concurrent request value. If active concurrent request are > than effective concurrency capacity, then scaling begins.
Basically 2-3 CPU heavy requests can bring effective concurrency from 80 to e.g. 9. Then you might have 10 fast light requests, bringing concurrent requests count to 10 and that can trigger scaling.
Also please bear in mind that the container CPU utilization metric is average of all containers instances.


effective concurrency
Interesting! I do have some long running requests (p95 - 2min). I have doubled my max concurrent requests. But it hasn't brought down the instance count.


Docs suggest that when an instance is configured to have 1000 max concurrency and 2vCPU limit, and each request takes 0.2vCPU to process, the effective capacity for the instance will just be 10 as we will reach CPU limit with 10 concurrent requests.
So increasing max concurrent requests might help.

I made it 1000 but still no change.

Cloud Run autoscaler is a complex thing. It scales based on CPU and Memory usage, but also on the traffic (number of requests to the service). In addition, min instance and max instance set the lower and higher bounds of the parallel instances.
More in the documentation here: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/about-instance-autoscaling

But even with this in mind it could be more complex. Cloud Run tries to optimize the number of instances available to absorb the traffic. That's why, according to the past traffic, the Cloud Run autoscaler will anticipate the future traffic based on heuristic and you can see an over provisioning of instances for a while.
Similarly, when you set a max instance, and because Cloud Run can kill instances and dispatch traffic as the load balancer wish, you can also see more CLoud Run instances provisioned than the max instance. but at each point of time, Cloud Run won't use more than instance in parallel than the max instance values.

A final word: The eng team continue to observe and to tune Cloud Run autoscaler according to the usage of the service. This logic (maybe already outdated) can be improved at any time.

A very generic answer.

Also, max concurrent requests (p99) is ~2, and sometimes 10. And I have set the max concurrent to 80.

That sounds consistent. Most of the time, you have a low number of instance. Sometime, when the traffic increase (from 2 to 10), the Cloud Run autoscaler do not know what will be the future, and it over provision instances. lower the latency between the request in  your "spike", higher the number of provisioned instances. When you rely on serverless services, you also rely on the implementation of the service and its (weird) behavior, limitations, quotas and super powerful feature.
